# problem with the task function in truffle development

Tags: solidity

[image]

I am doing the "TodoList" exercise and when I use truffle (development), I do not return the call with task, I get the following error:

```
truffle (development)> todoList = await TodoList.deployed ()
undefined
truffle (development)> task = await TodoList.task (1)
TypeError: TodoList.task is not a function
     at evalmachine. <anonymous>: 1: 16

Truffle version 5.0.22
```

This is my first post, your help will be very important to me[image]

Comment: The method is `tasks` according to the tutorial. Use `task = await todoList.tasks(1)`

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a link to [Gregory's tutorial](http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/blockchain-app-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am following that same tutorial. At the moment of entering the same function as you say, I get the following error:
TypeError: TodoList.task is not a function at evalmachine. : 1: 16

Comment: TodoList.task singular, is not the same as TodoList.tasks plural

Comment: I tried with tasks, but it did not work for me. What can be ?. I updated with another image

Comment: @Tlri Solidity is case sensitive so be extra careful. Try this exactly: `task = await TodoList.tasks (1)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
task = await todoList.tasks(1)
```

instead of

```
task = await TodoList.task (1)
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting the same problem but I have got the solution and the solution is that you have to restart your blockchain because sometimes it happen that it shows some useless error in evm
I hope it will help you since I use it and it help me:)))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error code you received was:

```
TypeError: TodoList.task is not a function at evalmachine. <anonymous>: 1: 16
```

Because you didn't declare any function named as `task`. You declared a function named as `tasks` at line 12:

```
mapping(uint => Task) public tasks;
```

So you can access to this function by adding an `s` when you call it :)

```
task = await TodoList.tasks(1)
```